# Order of boxes in raster

Tags: tcolorbox

The order in which boxes in a `raster` appear is important for me: **RTL** or **LTR**.

However, I was not able to find any documentation (in `tcolorbox` manual or here) of which enables control over this property.

In the following MWE, the first box in the code is on the left. I wish to have control over the order boxes are sorter.

In this example I would like that the right box will be the first written in the code.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2,]
\tcbitem1
\tcbitem2
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The order is always LTR and from top to bottom. If you want to change the appearance order, you have to change declaration order: `\tcbitem2 \tcbitem1`.

Comment: If you want to fix a box position with independence of the declaration order, you can use a `tcbposter` although is not so easy to manage like a `tcbraster` and it's not breakable.

Comment: there is a solution. see next post:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%:Language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\AtEndPreamble{
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{CMU Serif}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2,]
\tcbitem1
\tcbitem2
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```